# What is the database model?

Tags: c#, database, model-view-controller

**What is the "database model"? Is this an appropriate class to contain methods for reading and writing methods to the database?**

After studying MVC a bit, I'm confident in saying that the Model portion is where I should be communicating with the database. I currently have my entity classes (such as the classic "Person") and a class called DatabaseModel which has public methods for executing SQL queries on the database.

Then, in other classes in my controller, I create a DatabaseModel object, and execute the public methods within that class to retrieve SQL query results.

**Am I approaching this correctly?** Also, on a side note, I have a feeling this DatabaseModel class is going to become very large. Is there a good strategy for breaking this up (possibly for related queries). I thought of dividing it into partial classes in C#, but that's my best guess right now.

Answer (score 0):

Database models is the mapping structure for your database schema, in such case it will be the Entity class, so back to definition; that been said. In order to interact or query your Database you have 2 common patterns which you can follow, **DAO** pattern, and simply this is a class which will contain the main query operations for each entity **CRUD** operations or [ Save , Update and Delete ], that means if you have PersonEntity you should have PersonDAO.

The second pattern is **Repository** pattern, and I think you will have that in any powerful framework, and will support you with ready CRUD methods to use it directly with no need to write the definition code for each operation, unlike DAO pattern.

Speaking about code quantity in each class, actually it depends, however you should follow clean code strategies, that is for any class you shouldn’t do everything to find yourself having more than 400 lines of code, this as example.Unless you really need to have this.

Comment: Do you think this is a good example to follow for DAO? Fortunately, it seems straight forward unlike some other patterns (MVVM is currently killing me, not conceptually but actually implementing).

Example: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/data_access_object_pattern.htm

Comment: Also, if I create multiple concrete DAOs (for separate model objects and interfaces), would it be proper to create a class which wraps all of those concrete DAOs? This way I don't have to create multiple DAOs to access queries for different model objects?

Comment: You are totally correct, if you follow DAO pattern you may need to wrap them of course to aggregate your needs.

Answer (score 0):

**After studying MVC a bit, I'm confident in saying that the Model portion is where I should be communicating with the database. I currently have my entity classes (such as the classic "Person") and a class called DatabaseModel which has public methods for executing SQL queries on the database.**

Actually I disagree, this is the misconception I've had when I started. To me, M is the the mapping to the database, it is the database itself, using either entity framework or some other framework of your choice, so you can create a database using code first approach without ever touching SQL.

**Then, in other classes in my controller, I create a DatabaseModel object, and execute the public methods within that class to retrieve SQL query results.**

This should be a job for your repository, where you retrieve SQL query results, please keep in mind that this is not the actual controller.

**Am I approaching this correctly? Also, on a side note, I have a feeling this DatabaseModel class is going to become very large. Is there a good strategy for breaking this up (possibly for related queries). I thought of dividing it into partial classes in C#, but that's my best guess right now.**

You are almost there, what you have right now is the **Model**(Database mapping), the **Repository**(where you execute and retrieve data), but you are missing the **Controller**(where you get the repository using dependency injection and do the actual work, for example mapping the data to your **ViewModel**), your **ViewModel**(where you map the data so you only get and send what you need from the data to the view, this might seem like pointless at first, why can't we just send the data to the view, but it comes with many benefits, for example, you are only dealing with what you actually need, you can verify user input(client side validation) before mapping it back to data etc), and then finally the **View**(your display).

So to me, MVC is just a standard, it doesn't mean you only have the Model View and Controller, I never liked the acronym, it causes too much confusion at first, to me, it should be: **M(Model, the database mapping)C(Controller)VM(ViewModel)V(View)**, and also the repository between the Model and the Controller, but let's leave that out because it's a personal preference thing, most of the time people are just confused about the difference between the Model and the ViewModel.

Comment: So your project should be separated into something like this, your Entity classes or the Models, the repository dealing with the Model, the ViewModels, the Controllers and then the Views